# ViewPager switch simulation in thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-viewpager

I want to run something like photo show in my `activity`. I load fragments to the `ViewPager` and then just simulate switching views.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pager.setCurrentItem(0);
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Settings.showDelay*1000);
                    if(pager.getCurrentItem()==photos.size()-1){
                        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                                                      Thread.sleep(Settings.showDelay*1000);

                    }else

                        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()+1, true);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

        }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
```

I put it in my `onCreate` method and for 3 images it works perfectly but for 4 or more its:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process
```

Comment: Do not use thread to make the sliding animation As it will run on UI thread and make changes in UI. That is why its giving such error.

Comment: but i want these changes. i need to change currentItem in this pager without touch on screen

Comment: Try out with my code which i have posted as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out below code to switch the view pager. I have used it and it works like charm for me.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

public void SwitchPage(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
timer.schedule(new SwitchPageTask(), 6000, seconds * 1000); // delay in milliseconds
}


class SwitchPageTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // As the TimerTask run on a separate thread from UI thread we have
        // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                                  if(pager.getCurrentItem()==photos.size()-1)
                                  {
                                       pager.setCurrentItem(0);

                                  }else
                {pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);}
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Simply you need to pass the seconds to switch the viewpager. And it will keeps on running and switching to next items.

```
      SwitchPage(6); //it will switch the view on every 6 seconds.
```