# how to call the onBackPress() on the main thread of the process

Tags: android, multithreading, view, admob

I am new to admobi, I am adding interstitial adds, I want to close the add programmatically. After some research I found that it is not possible ,only this we need use onbackpress to close the add ,as it will closes when you press the backpress key .i have tried it but it is giving an error like
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process.
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2131)
i am trying to solve it from the lost two days it is not working please any body solve it and give it to me will be thank full.i am adding my code below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    protected boolean active = true;
    protected int splashtime = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4412961323059248/9600290618");
        final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
        //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        // Add a test device to show Test Adss
        /* .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
         .addTestDevice("9F0D0FB0280794109822A582BFFB7EC1")*/
         .build();  

        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        Thread splash = new Thread()

        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try
                {
                    int waitid = 0;
                    while(active && (waitid < splashtime))
                    {
                        sleep(1000);
                        if(active)
                        {
                            waitid+=100;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                finally
                {



                        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
                        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));


                }

            }
        };
        splash.start();

        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                //interstitial.show();
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could Someone Please answer this question as no one is answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so for so many research i found another way of solution by using timer which will work for me

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22147321/):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

 SwitchPage(6);

private void SwitchPage(int seconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
            timer.schedule(new SwitchPageTask(), 10000, seconds * 10000); // delay in milliseconds
    }
class SwitchPageTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // As the TimerTask run on a separate thread from UI thread we have
            // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
                    dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)); 
                    finish();
                    SwitchPageTask.this.cancel();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SwitchPageTask.this.cancel();
                    finish();
                    
                    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement key_up and key_down events inside Handler of main thread.
2. From inside your splash thread, send a message to the implemented handler to execute the key_up and key_down events.

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    protected boolean active = true;
    protected int splashtime = 3000;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Creating new Handler object
        handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
            dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));              
        }
        };

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4412961323059248/9600290618");
        final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
        //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

        // Add a test device to show Test Adss
        /* .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
     .addTestDevice("9F0D0FB0280794109822A582BFFB7EC1")*/
        .build();  

        // Load ads into Banner Ads
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        Thread splash = new Thread()

        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try
                {
                    int waitid = 0;
                    while(active && (waitid < splashtime))
                    {
                        sleep(1000);
                        if(active)
                        {
                            waitid+=100;
                        }
                    }
                }
                 catch (InterruptedException e) 
                 {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                 }
                 finally
                {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }

            }
        };
        splash.start();

        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                //interstitial.show();
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interstitial load is not loading now , and it is closing directly the view

Comment: was it loading before when you were getting the crash? cause I have not changed your logic. I just replaces key_up and key_down from finally block with sending message to handler.

Answer (score -1):

calll this where you want to perform backpress from your activity

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: i tried your answer its giving error like java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread of process. please read my full question as i described with code and please give me a solution

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });

Comment: +Akash kv Poorly written and poorly explained.